# The difference between peptide bonds and the bonds between polypeptides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, covalent-compounds

I was doing some tests for the multiple-choice final we've got ahead. And it was on me to count the peptide bonds in an Insulin hormone with 51 aminoacids arranged in two polypeptides with 30 and 21 aminoacids. (these are not true in reality) 
the number of bonds were 49, not 50, and that means the bond between two polypeptides doesn't count as a peptide bond. Additionally, I know that polypeptide bonds make the proteins' molecular structure, as it is now. (just look at that shape.) PEPTIDE COVALENT BONDS CAN NEVER cause that kind of 3d orientation in space. So there must be some fundamental difference between those bonds. What is it?
 My research couldn't find any results as simple things have jammed the internet.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from covalent bonds (amide and disulfide), the sturcture of a protein is determined by hydrogen bonds, [salt bridges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_bridge_(protein_and_supramolecular)), and less specific interactions such as hydrophobic and hydrophilic effects.  Hydrophobic portions of the protein chain tend toward the interior of the folded protein and hydrophilic regions to the exterior, in aqueous solution.

Answer (score 4):

The term peptide bond refers to amide bonds. The 21 amino acids in insulin's A-chain are covalently linked by 20 amide bonds. The 30 amino acids in insulin's B-chain are linked by 29 amide bonds. The two polypeptides are covalently linked by disulfide bonds, which are not amide bonds.

The 3D structure of proteins is a complex topic and a field of intense research. It's worth pointing out though that even polypeptides (with no disulfides or other covalent linkages) have a more complex 3D structure than you might expect. I suggest you look into [alpha-helices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_helix) and [beta-sheets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_sheet) as an entry into the topic.

Took some info from the [Beta Cell Consortium](http://www.betacell.org/content/articleview/article_id/8/).